# Dump GUID structure?

Tags: c#, php, c

The GUID structure apparently looks like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

How can I see what those DWORD/WORD/BYTE values are? I'm trying to spit them out [using C#](http://ideone.com/AfK0wg) but I don't know how to print them.

I don't care if this is done in C, C# or whatever language, I think Microsoft uses the same structure under the hood. I just need to be able to see the structure so I can debug my PHP script that needs to read these things. I don't have access to Visual Studio right now (I'm on Ubuntu).

---

How is this "too broad"? I'll make it more specific: given the GUID with hex representation `E20A9380-FD55-BCA5-9037-451C9D86E949` and binary representation `new byte[]{0x80,0x93,0x0a,0xe2,0x55,0xfd,0xa5,0xbc,0x90,0x37,0x45,0x1c,0x9d,0x86,0xe9,0x49}` I would like to know which of those bytes correspond to `Data1`, `Data2` and `Data3` and what their numeric values are.

The hyperlink above shows my attempt:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var guid = new Guid("E20A9380-FD55-BCA5-9037-451C9D86E949");
    Console.WriteLine(guid);
    PrintObj(guid);
}


public static void PrintObj(object obj)
{
    foreach(PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
    {
        string name=descriptor.Name;
        object value=descriptor.GetValue(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",name,value);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't print anything. Those aren't readable properties I guess.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I added another paragraph to better explain it. The "why" is that I'm writing a PHP app that is reading in some data generated by a Microsoft server. I need to parse it.

Comment: Show the code that's generating that byte array.

Comment: So really the question is "how can I parse c# guids in php?"

Comment: @AndrewMedico I did. I hyperlinked it in the very first version of this question.

Comment: Your code needs to be in your post.

Comment: The [Guid.ToByteArray method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains what's going on. `ToByteArray` produces the raw in-memory (little-endian) representation of the values that make up the GUID. Your parser needs to account for that.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Yeah, I've written the little-endian byte reader already, and I've created a PHP structure to mimic Microsoft's, but I want to confirm each of my dword/words match up with what MS is producing so I can figure out where I went wrong. Anyway, Aravol gave me what I needed.

Comment: @Mark Answers do not belong in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use C# on Ubuntu, look into Xamarin.

In C#, the [Guid Structre](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) exposes a [ToByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tobytearray.aspx) Which you could print byte by byte.

```
foreach(var b in id.ToBytearray()) Console.WriteLine("{0:X2}", b);
```

Or do some trnalsation using the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get each part seperately

```
var bytes = id.ToByteArray();
Console.WriteLine("Data1: {0:X8}", BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0));
Console.WriteLine("Data2: {0:X4}", BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 4));
Console.WriteLine("Data3: {0:X4}", BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 6));
Console.WriteLine("Data4: {0:X16}", BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 8));
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a class I use that enables some basic GUID manipulation. I'm sure it could be extended to do even more.

[EDIT: After playing around with this class, I noticed that the byte array was interpreted badly by my LittleEndian processor. I updated the public methods to account for this, and included ways of modifying the high-order bytes.]

```
public class GuidParts
{
    private byte[] _bytes;

    public GuidParts() : this(Guid.Empty)
    {
    }

    public GuidParts(Guid guid)
    {
        InitFromGuid(guid);
    }

    public GuidParts(string str)
    {
        var guid = Guid.Empty;
        if (Guid.TryParse(str, out guid))
        {
            InitFromGuid(guid);
        }
    }

    public Int32 Data1 { get; set; }
    public Int16 Data2 { get; set; }
    public Int16 Data3 { get; set; }

    public Int64 Data4
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt64(_bytes, 0); }
        set { _bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value); } 

    }

    public byte[] Data4Bytes
    {
        get { return _bytes; }
        set { _bytes = SafeCopy(value, 8); }
    }

    public Int16 Data4High
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt16(_bytes, 0); }
        set { Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, _bytes, 0, 2); }
    }

    public Int16 Data4HighReverse
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt16(ReverseArray(_bytes), 0); }
        set { Buffer.BlockCopy(ReverseArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value)), 0, _bytes, 0, 2); }
    }

    public Int64 Data4Reverse
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt64(ReverseArray(_bytes), 0); }
        set { _bytes = ReverseArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(value)); }
    }

    public Guid ToGuid()
    {
        return new Guid(Data1, Data2, Data3, _bytes);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToGuid().ToString("B");
    }

    #region private

    private void InitFromGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        var b = guid.ToByteArray();
        Data1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);
        Data2 = BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 4);
        Data3 = BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 6);
        _bytes = new[] { b[8], b[9], b[10], b[11], b[12], b[13], b[14], b[15] };
    }

    // Because Array.Reverse modifies the original array and returns void. Yuck.
    private T[] ReverseArray<T>(T[] input) where T : new()
    {
        int from = input.Length, to = 0;
        T[] reversed = new T[from];
        while (from-- > 0) reversed[to++] = input[from];
        return reversed;
    }

    private T[] SafeCopy<T>(T[] input, int count) where T : new()
    {
        T[] copied = new T[count];
        int position = 0, length = input.Length;
        while (position < length) copied[position] = input[position++];
        return copied;
    }

    #endregion
}
```